# How to fix multiple if codes in python

Tags: python, performance

My python code is ugly.
How to tune this code?

```
find_list1 = re.findall(p1, path)
find_list2 = re.findall(p2, path)
find_list3 = re.findall(p3, path)
if len(find_list1) > 0:find_list = find_list1
if len(find_list2) > 0:find_list = find_list2
if len(find_list3) > 0:find_list = find_list3
if len(re.findall(p1, path)) > 0:date_str1 += re.findall(p1, path)[0] + " " 
if len(re.findall(p2, path)) > 0:date_str2 += re.findall(p2, path)[0] + " " 
if len(re.findall(p3, path)) > 0:date_str3 += re.findall(p3, path)[0] + " " 
if len(date_str1) > 0:date_str = date_str1
if len(date_str2) > 0:date_str = date_str2
if len(date_str3) > 0:date_str = date_str3
```

Thank you.

Comment: This code isn't runnable as-is, so I can't run it and play with it to show you exactly how to clean it up while verifying that it still does the same thing, but the general strategy I'd suggest would be to use lists rather than groups of 3 variables.  The first six lines, for example, could be `find_lists = [re.findall(p, path) for p in (p1, p2, p3)]` and then `find_list = max(find_lists, key=bool)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing if/how these intermediate variables are used it's difficult to be optimal.

Assuming that `find_list`, `date_str`, `date_str1`, `date_str2` and `date_str3` had previous content, and that `find_list1`, `find_list2` and  `find_list3` are used later, the code could be written as follows to make it a bit more compact and avoid re-computing values already obtained on previous lines.

```
find_list1 = re.findall(p1, path)
find_list2 = re.findall(p2, path)
find_list3 = re.findall(p3, path)
if find_list1: date_str1 += find_list1[0] + " "
if find_list2: date_str2 += find_list2[0] + " "
if find_list3: date_str3 += find_list3[0] + " "
find_list = find_list3 or find_list2 or find_list1 or find_list
date_str  = date_str3  or date_str2  or date_str1  or date_str
```

The use of `or` leverages short-circuiting and Python's implicit "truthy" value of lists (an empty list is False, a non-empty list is True).  So doing `A = B or C` for lists assigns B if it is not empty (which short circuits the `or`). If B is empty (False) then `or` proceeds to the next operand and returns C.   The one-line assignments to `find_list` and `date_str` produce the same result as the series of `if` statements  (the order of operands is important though)